# Thread.activeCount is giving me back an active count of 2 threads instead of 1 thread why?

Tags: java

> public class Prac {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(Thread.activeCount());

    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());

}
```

}

................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

> 

should return 1 thread

Comment: Garbage collector runs as a thread. Event Dispatch Thread could also be running. The JVM has multiple threads itself.

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://ideone.com/Ek01Y0

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, Java uses a thread to monitor for ctrl-break being typed.

If you look at the implementation of `Thread.activeCount()`:

```
    /**
     * Returns an estimate of the number of {@linkplain #isAlive() live}
     * platform threads in the current thread's thread group and its subgroups.
     * Virtual threads are not included in the estimate.
     *
     * <p> The value returned is only an estimate because the number of
     * threads may change dynamically while this method traverses internal
     * data structures, and might be affected by the presence of certain
     * system threads. This method is intended primarily for debugging
     * and monitoring purposes.
     *
     * @return  an estimate of the number of live platform threads in the
     *          current thread's thread group and in any other thread group
     *          that has the current thread's thread group as an ancestor
     */
    public static int activeCount() {
        return currentThread().getThreadGroup().activeCount();
    }
```

It refers only to threads in the thread group of which the current thread (i.e. main) is a member.

We can print the threads in the current thread group to the console:

```
        Thread.currentThread().getThreadGroup().list();
```

Which on GNU/Linux (WSL2 anyway) prints:

```
java.lang.ThreadGroup[name=main,maxpri=10]
    Thread[#1,main,5,main]
    Thread[#26,Monitor Ctrl-Break,5,main]
```

If you want to find out more about current threads, use the `ThreadMXBean`:

```
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import java.lang.management.ThreadInfo;
import java.lang.management.ThreadMXBean;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(Thread.activeCount());

        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        Thread.currentThread().getThreadGroup().list();
        ThreadMXBean threadMXBean = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean();
        long[] ids = threadMXBean.getAllThreadIds();
        for (long id: ids) {
            ThreadInfo threadInfo = threadMXBean.getThreadInfo(id);
            System.out.println(threadInfo);
        }
    }
}
```